# Port 80 outside is only available for IIS, how can I open it for other services and applications?

Tags: apache, iis, firewall, windows-server-2016

The server is running on Windows Server 2016.

IIS runs on port 80, Apache on 8080. Both are visible from the outside, the pages of each open, everything is ok.

I run certbot (to make a certificate) and, as stated in the instructions, turn off IIS so that certbot will bring up its web server on port 80 and activate the certificate. But it gives an error Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem).

I disable IIS, switch Apache to port 80, locally accessible but not outside!

I tried to unbind IIS site from port 80, it did not help.

I checked the windows firewall, 80 was opened and remains.

Where to dig?

Comment: If you let IIS run as reverse proxy, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing then all traffic can arrive at port 80 and then forward to the right places.

Comment: A port in the windows system can only serve one process. When IIS uses port 80, other processes may not be able to use it. Closing IIS does not completely stop port 80, you need to find the process and stop it.

Answer (score 0):

The rule in firewall was allowed only for the IIS process. Therefore, disabling the IIS freed up the port, but the firewall blocked it for any other applications. I changed the rule to any application (process) and it worked :)